# Клонирование таблиц в одной БД SQLite 3 C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

Собственно, есть ли возможность (простое решение) создать полную копию существующей таблицы с данными?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291165/sqlite-copy-data-from-one-table-to-another || https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: Спасибо, но INSERT INTO... предусматривает уже созданную новую таблицу с идентичной структурой. Конечно, можно сначала выполнить команды CREATE TABLE..., а затем выполнить INSERT INTO - это работает. Но хотелось бы найти решение, как автоматизировать процесс, чтобы не задавать при создании новой таблицы структуру исходной.